# Reuse parts of a nextjs app on the console using node command

Tags: node.js, next.js

I created a problem repository here:

```
https://github.com/tippfelher/so-nextjs-console
```

**Problem description:**

Using `yarn next dev` starts the development server which successfully outputs the model `Example` on the `index`-Page.

However, I cannot reuse the same model in a console application.

Running `node .\console-app` produces the error

```
import Example from "../models/Example";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

**Attempts to solve this problem:**

Add `{ "type": "module" }` to root `package.json` and change `next.config.js` contents to

```
const config = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

export default config;
```

triggers error:

```
Error: require() of ES Module <PATH>\demo\nextjs-node\app\.next\server\pages\_document.js from <PATH>\demo\nextjs-node\app\node_modules\next\dist\server\require.js not supported.
```

**Edit**

```
node --version
v16.13.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not specify the node version but that error looks like the version of node requires enabling the  then experimental es6 module support. In `package.json` add

```
"type": "module",
```

In new NodeJS builds looks like import statements are [supported](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-specifiers).
Since this is posted around Next, you may get into other compatibility issues, the `yarn next dev` invokes a `cli` which does a build and packages compatible modules to be executed by `node`.

If you are curious, checkout the `cli` build - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next/cli

Comment: I added the node version to my initial post. Thanks for pointing that out.

I do however wrote, that `"type": "module"` does not work. (basically kills the nextjs application)

Comment: ok, you may want to note the addition of type:module and when you say it kills application, I am confused - you are just running a script file located inside a nextjs directory via node

Comment: To be honest. I don't understand what you are trying to say. As I said, and also pointed out in my initial "own attempts" section is that adding "type": "module" prevents me from starting my nextjs application. Even if this would fix the `node` command problem there is no point when my nextjs application cannot run anymore.

Comment: My bad, I was able to create a codesandbox and ran into your same problem, co-existence in this sense seems a problem. I tried creating a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-cdn-ut7hp?file=/package.json and a new npm script that runs with the `experimental-modules` flag however it seems that this does not end up working, I am still trying to validate your original ask though, even when the nextjs application breaks and the nodejs works, it errors out  when it hits the html blocks of the index file. It might be better to separate these projects or use a monorepo at that point.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I gave up on this problem now and implemented the console app as a command which can be invoked using the REST-Api. <3

Comment: Thank you, glad you were able to pick a direction !